# ORA-08103: object no longer exists occurred while altering tables

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a stored procedure that simply enables constraints of specific tables.

It has been working fine for quite a while, but all of sudden(today), I got ORA-08103 error.

What could be the cause of this error?

```
  BEGIN
    FOR c IN (
    SELECT
      c.owner,
      c.table_name,
      c.constraint_name
    FROM user_constraints c
    WHERE c.status = 'DISABLED'
          AND c.table_name IN (
      'TABLE_01', 'TABLE_02', 'TABLE_03', 'TABLE_04'
    )) LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || c.table_name || ' ENABLE CONSTRAINT ' || c.constraint_name;
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

[Update]

- Disable constraints
- Load bulk data
- Enable constraints

These are steps I am following.

First, I disable the constrains of the tables, then load bulk data using SQLLoader and finally enable the disabled constraints, where I get ORA-08103 error.

Comment: Is there a possibility that one of those 4 tables ***no longer exists*** ?

Comment: @Rafalon No, they are always there. They will never be dropped.

Comment: Well, one of the constraints then ? Did you try to run the `Select` clause only to check what results you get ?

Comment: The same goes for the constraints.

Comment: Yes, I get the result as expected.

Comment: If the table didn't exist the error would be _"ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"_. If the constraint didn't exist it would be _"ORA-02430: cannot enable constraint (XYZ) - no such constraint"_. ORA-08103 refers to the internal data segment.

Answer (score 4):

ORA-08103 occurs when we try to run a DDL statement against an object which doesn't exist. Ah, but you say

> they are always there. They will never be dropped

Database objects like tables have two identifiers in the data dictionary, the OBJECT_ID and the DATA_OBJECT_ID: we can see these in [the ALL_OBJECTS view](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-AA6DEF8B-F04F-482A-8440-DBCB18F6C976.htm#REFRN20146). The OBJECT_ID is constant for the lifetime of the table but the DATA_OBJECT_ID  -  the "dictionary object number of the segment that contains the object" - changes any time DDL is executed against the object. For instance, when a table is truncated or an index is rebuilt.

So to your situation: the ORA-08103 error indicates that the DATA_OBJECT_ID has changed since you ran the cursor. That is while you were running your procedure somebody else executed DDL against one of the tables, constraints or underlying indexes.

Probably this is an unfortunate coincidence and it won't happen the next time you run the procedure. But you can minimize the chances of another occurrence by changing the way you run the query:

```
declare
    tabs dbms_debug_vc2coll := dbms_debug_vc2coll ('TABLE_01', 'TABLE_02', 'TABLE_03', 'TABLE_04');
BEGIN
    for idx in 1..tabs.count() loop
        FOR c IN (
            SELECT
                c.owner,
                c.table_name,
                c.constraint_name
            FROM user_constraints c
            WHERE c.table_name = tabs(idx)
            AND c.status = 'DISABLED'
          ) LOOP
             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || c.table_name || ' ENABLE CONSTRAINT ' || c.constraint_name;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Enabling constraints takes time (because of the need to validate them). So selecting tables one by one reduces the time you need the DATA_OBJECT_ID to remain fixed.

---

> "How does your procedure above minimize the chance of the same error?"

Your cursor selects all four tables, and hence all four DATA_OBJECT_IDs. Suppose another session modifies TABLE_04 while you are enabling constraints on TABLE_01. When your procedure gets round to TABLE_04 the DATA_OBJECT_ID has changed and you'll get ORA-08103.

But if you were running my version of the code it wouldn't matter, because you would not select the DATA_OBJECT_ID for TABLE_04 until you were ready to process it. So you would get the changed DATA_OBJECT_ID (without knowing it was changed.

Comment: How does your procedure above minimize the chance of the same error?

Comment: From my observation, I think this might also have something to do with DB specs.

Comment: Thank you for useful suggestion. I have modified my procedure as you suggested and run it. Although I made sure that no one else would do any type of operations to the tables, I still got the same error.

Comment: If there really is no other session interfering with what you're doing it must be some side effect of your process.  Alas there's not much more I can do about this. I have told you the sort of thing which causes the error. Now you are going to have to break this down by yourself. Start with, what changed yesterday (or since the last successful run)? If that doesn't help, put some logging into procedure to see which ones run and which one breaks.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will dig into this.